# Get SQL INSERT OUTPUT value in c#

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

In a SQL stored proc i'm inserting a row and hoping to return the IDENTITY INT for the new row, then get it in my C# code.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE the_proc @val_2 VARCHAR(10), @val_3 VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
INSERT INTO the_table (field_2, field_3)
  OUTPUT INSERTED.field_1
  VALUES (@val_2, @val_3)
END
```

In C# i'm using LINQ but am fuzzy on how to retrieve that OUTPUT value. I tried including it as an OUTPUT parameter in the SQL proc declaration, but couldn't get that working either (exceptions complaining about it not being supplied in the call). The closest i've gotten is in walking into the Db.designer.cs code, where `IExecuteResult result` ReturnValue contains 0 (not correct) but inspecting the contained Results View (`result.ReturnValue Results View`) DOES have the outputed value.

```
key = (int)(db.TheProc(val2,val3).ReturnValue);
```

`key` is coming back as 0. I want the IDENTITY INT value from the INSERT.

Comment: Have you tried running the procedure by hand, to make sure that it really returns the identity int? You may need to use @@Identity instead of INSERTED.field_1

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - The OP's procedure will work fine. His approach is more robust then selecting `@@identity` as it will work correctly if an insert trigger is added to the table.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - as i mentioned, when inspecting the Results in the VS debugger, the IDENTITY INT is there (but not in the ReturnValue). So it's being returned somehow. What i'm asking for is the C# / Linq idiom for retrieving that value. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
OUTPUT INSERTED.*
```

is basically the same thing as doing a select.  So this isn't going to show up as an output parameter but rather come back as a result set.

BTW, the ReturnValue should actually be zero which is what you are seeing in this case.

You'll need to change your linq statement so that you capture that result set.

Comment: Well, you made me work for it but you got me on the right track. I'll accept this though but add an answer with the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead (assuming SQL Server) :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE the_proc 
@val_2 VARCHAR(10), 
@val_3 VARCHAR(10), 
@newKey int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON
  INSERT INTO the_table (field_2, field_3) VALUES (@val_2, @val_3)
  SET @newKey = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

Once you define your the_proc stored procedure to your LINQ to SQL dbml you can do this:

```
        int? newKey = null;
        dataContext.the_proc("val1", "val2", ref newKey);
        // newKey.Value now contains your new IDENTITY value
```

Comment: hmmm... if i have to, i will, but what's puzzling me here is that i don't know how to get the OUTPUT INSERTED value. It **IS** in there somewhere; as i said i can see it in the VS debugger by inspecting `result.ReturnValue Results View`

Comment: If the ReturnValue you see in VS always has the value 0 it is very likely not what you're wanting.  Stored procedures have an int ReturnValue output that indicate success or failure.  See the bottom of this post: http://www.cleardata.biz/articles/storedproc.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Chris Lively nudged me in the right direction, which is to say re-examining the C# Linq code. The following pulls Field_1 out of the results. Maybe it's a weird way to get there and not the normal idiom, so if anyone has suggestions for something more "correct" please add a comment or answer.

```
var o = from res in db.MyProc( Val1, Val2 )
           select res.Field_1;
int key = o.ToArray()[0];
```

Thanks.

Comment: Glad you got this.  I'm not that good with Linq yet, otherwise I would have added it.  Regardless, this is the right way.